# systray disappeared

Tags: system-tray

running ubuntu 12.04 - all well after installation -
looking for some options in compiz do organize expo and other desktop stuff, now
systray-panel (= program-menus cant be shown and icons unvisible and no logoff,...) 
is not drawn at the top of screen/desktops
the launcher at left doesnt appear while moving mouse to then left
any programs can only be started via command-line by getting a terminal with ctrl-alt-T

how can I start/show it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset unity using this command line

```
unity --reset
```

This will reset all unity setting to default.

or

```
ccsm
```

Comment: no problem Sir! Enjoy Ubuntu!

Comment: Be aware that resetting Unity will remove your desktop/launcher customizations and bring all open windows to the first virtual workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Open compiz config settings manager from a terminal using the command

```
ccsm
```

Then go to the desktop section and click on the `unity desktop plugin` and select `enable`.

After a few seconds the top & side bars should re-load.