# Upgraded to 13.10 now clock settings are all disabled and clock does not display

Tags: 13.10, system-tray, notification-area, clock

I've upgraded to 13.10 and now I don't have the standard menu clock, which I need for work.

I checked and 'indicator-datetime' is installed.  I even uninstalled/reinstalled that applet with no luck.

Also my "clock" settings under System Preferences are all disabled.  I can't change anything.

Does anyone know how I can get the old menu clock back?

Alternatively is there another menu clock app I can download?

**Edit 1**

Thanks for the responses

1. I've restarted several times and that didn't fix the issue.
2. I just ran the 13.10 update today.  But I ran it again a few minutes ago.  I got   about 200KB in random updates.  The issue is still present after a reboot.
3. `# apt-cache policy indicator-datetime
   indicator-datetime:
   Installed: 13.10.0+13.10.20131016.2-0ubuntu1
   Candidate: 13.10.0+13.10.20131016.2-0ubuntu1
   Version table:
   *** 13.10.0+13.10.20131016.2-0ubuntu1 0
       500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
       100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

**Edit 2**

I believe the issue is related to 'rarings' changing the systray somehow...
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/raring-retires-system-tray-whitelist

Or [systray disappeared](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154970/systray-disappeared), although I haven't got that solution to work yet.

**Edit 3**

Because of a suggestion from RolandiXor I've check the binaries.  My system is missing 'libical.so.0' but it has 'libical.so.1'.

```
ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-datetime-service
libical.so.0 => not found
```

Does anyone know how to get the libical.so.0 binary that the datetime service needs but doesn't install?

Comment: Are you sure you are up to date? Check the updater please. This bug should have been fixed already.

Comment: Can you add the output of `apt-cache policy indicator-datetime`?

Comment: I have this same issue. I've found that doing a purge of indicator-datetime, reinstalling, and logging out will bring back the clock and all settings. However after one or two reboots the problem returns.

Comment: Have you run `indicator-datetime` manually? (You can find its location on your system by running `locate indicator-datetime`).

Comment: Just had the same issue with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Had to use killall unity-panel-service

Comment: This is present in 14.04 also.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

There's a bug report for that in [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-datetime/+bug/1228360).

Quick fix:
Open terminal (ctrl + alt + T) and type

```
killall unity-panel-service
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've restarted the computer many times.  It's not a process restart issue.

Comment: Or you can just press "Alt+F2" and type the same and it will work.

Comment: Marking as answer as it's probably what most readers will need.  But for me it was a library loading path problem due to the fact that the datetime service seems to load from /usr/local before /usr for some reason.

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: Worked for me, but I need to do this again sometimes when I reboot

Comment: Use 'restart unity-panel-service', there is no need for reboot.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I performed a reboot and my clock is back.

Comment: Thanks, but I've restarted the computer many times. It's not a process restart issue.

Comment: killall unity-panel-service this worked like a charm for me ,no need for repoot :D

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.  I built a few libraries from source earlier in `/usr/local/lib` .  indicator-datetime-service found those libraries *before* the system libraries in `/usr/lib` for some reason.  It shouldn't have done that.

One of those libraries pulled in the old libical.so.0 dependency which was no longer available.  When I deleted all the GNOME/Evolution related libraries in `/usr/local/lib` I could start indicator-datetime-service again and my clock shown up.

So also try...

```
ldd --verbose /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-datetime-service
```

And look for any "not found" messages in the output.  If you have a library dependency issue it will most likely show up in that output.

Comment: while that might have solved your specific issue, i tried that procedure and got no "not found"'s.  is that because i ran that AFTER "fixing" the issue with the accepted answer?

Comment: @kervin: Running this check on my Desktop 14.0.2 LTS (x86_64 with kernel v 3.16.0-41-generic) had the same results as that reported in the above comment. And I have not fixed anything yet, contrary to him. Would you care to elaborate on how to proceed on the "missing library" or PATH front ? I am stuck. Tx.

Comment: @kervin: File was no found because (perhaps in newer versions of the kernel) the path for that file is: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-service` ......... I don't know what is going on here.  Any hint or help so I can further try to solve this hih¡ghly appreciated.. I am stuck. Tx.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, (no clock displayed and settings disabled)
I had to select the default server for update in System Preferences.
Reboot, and the clock was back.

Comment: It was likely just the reboot that fixed your issue.